# Changing Imshow() axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axes

I created a imshow() plot in python as show below, I would like to replace the y-axis with [0 to 1000] instead of [0 to 5000] and x-axis with [0 to 150]. Could someone tell me what is best way to do it.

[image: Imshow() image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of the `extent` and `aspect` parameters of [`plt.imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(100, 100)

plt.imshow(img, extent=[0, 10, 0, 20], aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The extent parameter doesn't change my labels, It just rescales my image. I don't want to rescale, I just want to replace it. For example in matlab you can just say :  images(X,Y,Img) to change the axis label.

Comment: When I run the code I posted, the x-axis runs from 0 to 10 and the y-axis runs from 0 to 20. The labels are automatically adapted. What do you mean by "it just rescales my image?". Could you post an example image of what you're trying to achieve?